# Sharp Architecture - NewtonSoft.Json assembly mismatch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net, sharp-architecture

1. Create a fresh Sharp Architecture project.
2. Successfully build, create DB, run Web app.
3. Attempt to add a new entity to the database via the web View.
4. Get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue:**

The **Newtonsoft.Json** package was not updated due to the `-Safe` param added in the Sharp Architecture instructions

**Solution:**

1. Manually update the NewtonSoft.Json package via the Package Manager Console:

   Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json
2. Update the binding references *for each project* that includes that package via the Package Manager Console:

   Add-BindingRedirect

Comment: Is there no way to go without this tools. I hate microsoft paradigm of stacking tools on tools on tools... Each new tool introdeuces some random unwanted behaviour requiring yet more tools. I would love to see ti just work.